# Is it possible to use overloaded operators with "this" in instance methods?

Tags: c++

I am making a linked list and one of the methods required is to print the data of the linked list.  I attempted to use a loop and overloaded `[]` operators (returns the data type `T` of the indexed node) to print the list like so:

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < length; i++){
    cout << this[i] << endl;
}
```

The compiler is throwing an error that `cout` does not support type `const LinkedList<T>`, despite this code working in my test file:

```
LinkedList<int> newList = LinkedList<T>();
populateList
cout << newList[5] << endl;
```

I suspect my syntax for using the overloaded brackets operator with `this` is incorrect, could someone elaborate why?

EDIT2:

Deleted raw code snippet as to avoid any potential academic honesty issues.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], not just snippets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to write `(*this)[i]`, since the overloaded `[]` operator belongs to the class itself, but `this` is just a pointer.

The expression `this[i]` is valid, but in general `p[i]` where `p` is a pointer is interpreted as `*(p + i)`, so it's not doing what you want it to do.

Comment: Alternatively, `cout << this->operator[](i)`.  Or less silly but still not idiomatic C++, `auto const& self = *this; cout << self[i];`.